# Regular Expression Special Case PHP

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a regular expression that allows letters, Ñ and ñ, single quote ('), dash (-), period (.) and comma (,) and character space (input from spacebar) but prevent number input and any other character.

```
regex:/^[\pL\s\-',.0-9]+$/u
```

Am I getting the right idea with this? I'm a little confused because it still accepts number inputs.

Comment: You put in `0-9` of course it matches numbers.

Comment: I don't quite understand because even if I remove 0-9, it still accepts numbers

Comment: whatever you want to prevent from string than use Regex like  - **/[^0-9]/g**  it's not allow number

Comment: `regex:/^(?!\d+$)[\pL\d ',.-]+$/`

Answer (score 3):

I guess you mean that the input must not be *only digits*. You could use `(*SKIP)(*FAIL)` here:

```
^\d+$(*SKIP)(*FAIL)|^[-\pL ',.\d]+$
```

See [**a demo on regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/yb0L9Y/1/).

Comment: No i mean it must not have any digit